# Take an array of pairs of strings and return an array of arrays of all connected items

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, time-complexity

I have an array of pairs of names like:

```
[
  ['alison', 'jason'],
  ['alison', 'chris'],
  ['john', 'bill'],
  ['bill', 'alex'],
  ['alex', 'jack']
]
```

and I'm trying to write a method that can take this, and return

```
[
  ['alison', 'jason', 'chris'],
  ['john', 'bill', 'alex', 'jack']
]
```

in better than O(N^2) time. My attempt at this was as so:

```
def teams(arr)
  pair_hash = {}
  arr.each do |pair|
    if pair_hash[pair[0]].nil?
      pair_hash[pair[0]] = [pair[1]]
    else
      pair_hash[pair[0]].push(pair[1])
    end
  end
  teams = []
  pair_hash.map do |leader, team|
    teams.push(find_teammates(pair_hash, leader, team))
  end
  teams
end

def find_teammates(hash, leader, team)
  result = [leader]
  team.each do |member|
    if hash[member].nil?
      result += [member]
    else
      result += find_teammates(hash, member, hash[member])
    end
  end
  result
end
```

but this solution has extra teams in the result, and every solution I can think of involves having really poor time complexity. If you have any idea how to solve this without just brute forcing through all the pairs, I'd love to know.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to split the graph into connected components.
I belive I have seen something you need in [ruby graph library](https://github.com/monora/rgl)

Comment: A disjoint-set data structure would solve your problem in near-linear time: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). I'm seeing numerous Ruby gems out there which implement it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're lucky that disjoint-set is my favorite data structure. Here's a quick'n'dirty implementation:

```
pairs = [['alison', 'jason'], ['alison', 'chris'], ['john', 'bill'], ['bill', 'alex'], ['alex', 'jack'], ['steve', 'alex']]

parents = {}

pairs.each do |x, y|
  # each person starts as their own set, and their own representative
  parents[x] ||= x
  parents[y] ||= y

  # find representative of x set
  x_parent = parents[x]
  loop do
    break if parents[x_parent] == x_parent
    x_parent = parents[x_parent]
  end

  # find representative of y set
  y_parent = parents[y]
  loop do
    break if parents[y_parent] == y_parent
    y_parent = parents[y_parent]
  end

  # union by changing y's representative
  parents[y_parent] = x_parent
  # path compression to speed up later unions
  parents[x] = x_parent
  parents[y] = x_parent
end

# group by set representative (some paths might not be compressed)
groups = parents.each_key.group_by do |person|
  parent = parents[person]
  loop do
    break if parents[parent] == parent
    parent = parents[parent]
  end
  parent
end

p groups.values
[["alison", "jason", "chris"], ["john", "bill", "alex", "jack", "steve"]]
```

This is approximately O(N+M) where N is the number of people and M is the number of pairs. Notice the repetition e.g. in looking up a set's representative. The algorithm looks a lot cleaner if you define a proper class for doing the lookup.

Also my path compression is not ideal, you can speed it up even more if you put the compression inside the representative lookup rather than the union.